# Порядок загрузки скрипта в JS

Tags: javascript

Почитал уже несколько подобных тем и официальную документацию и все равно не понял.
Есть вот такой код

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>1</p>            
        <p>2</p>
        <script src="1.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

В файле 1.js обычный алерт. Насколько я понял, сначала должны отобразиться теги `<p>` , а затем уже алерт. Но почему-то все получается наоборот. Я пробовал использовать и `async` и `defer` - результат тот же
Подскажите, в чем проблема? В какую сторону копать?
Заранее спасибо

UPD Проблема наблюдается в хроме, но отсутствует в Файрфоксе

Comment: В сторону DOM...

Comment: проблема в браузере, можно считать это фичей.

Comment: Вы не правильно понимаете. Нет никакой гарантии и четких инструкций что браузер обязан рендерить страницу перед выполнением скриптов, скорее наоборот, наиболее правильно поведение, вначале применить _возможные_ изменения DOM из JS скриптов, а затем в первый раз от рисовать страницу.